# LaTeX3 Defining conditional functions

Tags: latex3

I ran into a problem when creating a new condition. The meaning of the condition `\foo_if_eq` is to check the global variable `\g_my_tl` for compliance with a certain string `bar`, the result is *true/false*.
The condition is created and works, but when inserting it into another condition, an error is generated at the build stage - *Missing number, treated as zero*. I can't understand the reason for the error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage {expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \g_my_tl
\tl_gset:Nn \g_my_tl {bar}

\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \foo_if_eq:n #1 {p, T, F, TF}
{
  \tl_if_eq:NnTF \g_my_tl {#1}
    { \prg_return_true:  }
    { \prg_return_false: }
}

\NewDocumentCommand {\testNewConditional} {}
{
  \foo_if_eq:nTF {bar} % OK
    {TRUE}{FALSE} \\

  \bool_if:nTF { \foo_if_eq_p:n {bar} } % FAIL (Missing number, treated as zero)
    {TRUE}{FALSE} \\
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  \testNewConditional
\end{document}

\endinput
```

If I use `\str_if_eq` instead of `\tl_if_eq` in the new check, then the build goes without errors and everything works correctly. Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage {expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \g_my_tl
\tl_gset:Nn \g_my_tl {bar}

\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \foo_if_eq:n #1 {p, T, F, TF}
{
  \str_if_eq:VnTF \g_my_tl {#1}
    { \prg_return_true:  }
    { \prg_return_false: }
}

\NewDocumentCommand {\testNewConditional} {}
{
 \foo_if_eq:nTF {bar} % OK
    {TRUE}{FALSE} \\

  \bool_if:nTF { \foo_if_eq_p:n {bar} } % OK
    {TRUE}{FALSE} \\
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  \testNewConditional
\end{document}

\endinput
```

Comment: the argument to `\bool_if:nTF ` needs to expand  to a boolean but you have `\tl_set:Nn` which is a non-expandable assignment

Comment: Depending on what you want to compare, you might try with `\str_if_eq:nnTF`

Comment: I corrected the example by removing the setting of the temporary variable `\l_tmpa_tl` from it, but this did not change the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create predicates which use functions which are not fully expandable (marked with a star in `interface3`). Here, `\tl_if_eq:nn` is not expandable, so it *cannot* be used inside the definition of a predicate. In contrast, `\str_if_eq:nn` is expandable so can be.